# Boostrap 3 active state button. How get total active button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

At page I have many button active state of type. I bind to the event click and check how many button have active status. But  when I click at first button I get zero.

```
$(".btn-quote").on("click", function (e) {
    var totalActiveQuote= $(".btn-quote.active").length;

    if (totalActiveQuote > 0) {
        console.log("active");
    } else {
        console.log("deactive");
    }
});
```

What I should  do to fix this?

**jsfiddle.net**

https://jsfiddle.net/haqkbvbh/

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `active` class is toggled after your `onClick` event fires. You could fix it by toggling it on your own.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn-quote").on("mouseup", function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("myActive");
    var totalActiveQiote = $(".btn-quote.myActive").length;
    $("#totalActive").html(totalActiveQiote);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could circumvent this by e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".btn-quote").on("click", function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        var totalActiveQiote = $(".active").length;

        $("#totalActive").html(totalActiveQiote);
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zpqcac1h/